# how to loop on every sheets and rename the sheet base on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to iterate over all sheets on another workbook and change the every sheets name based on the cell value. my code for looping can visit every sheet if i only msgbox the name of the sheet but if i rename it - only the first sheet can be renamed and the others will not, second loop is not going though.[enter image description here][1]

```
Dim i As Integer, ws_count As Integer, callNewWB As Workbook
Set callNewWB = [new workbook to rename the sheets]
ws_count = callNewWB.Sheets.Count

For i = 1 To ws_count

    callNewWB.Sheets(i).Select
    callNewWB.Sheets(i).Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Masterlist").Cells(i + 3, 2)

Next i
```

[image: IMG1]

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. What is the second loop?

Comment: Hi @JohnyL, I have created a new workbook where there are 5 sheets. the loop I have shared is to visit every sheets and rename the sheets base on the cell value of Masterlist sheet. my problem on my code is, out of 5 sheets it only change 1 sheet i.e that vvv sheet.

Comment: To debug: please add `Dim s$` and `s = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Masterlist").Cells(i + 3, 2)` before you .name and single cycle (F8) and verify that the 2nd newname is valid.  And what is your error message?